vim group and substitute
I have a csv file that contains 3 sets of ids. I want to use Vim to substitute the appropriate id into the appropriate places, e.g.
   A | B | C |
1| 1 | 2 | 3 |
2|33 |11 | 31|

How i can to replace rows from csv like this in this exact order:
update table set id1 = 2, id2 = 3 where id3 = 1;
update table set id1 = 11, id2 = 31 where id3 = 33;


if you add the CSV to the question, people can help you. Otherwise you can not expect much support.

at the beginning I added a screenshot with the data, but you are right, I shared a file with an example of the data

It's very unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. A vim command for modifying a CSV file? If so: please add an example input and the expected result to the question (no link, no screenshots!)

A question here is supposed to be self-contained, i.e. include all relevant information. Don't link to external file, instead add a sample if it in your question here.

What has this to do with SQL? What is your question? "I want" or "I would like" is none.

How i can to replace  rows from file and replace to sql script

Add a few more of csv data, and also specify the expected result.

Assuming your CSV contains fields separated by comma and lines separated by newline you could use the following substitution command:
:%s/\(\d\+\),\(\d\+\),\(\d\+\)/update table set id1 = \2, id2 = \3 where id3 = \1;


:%s a substitution acting on all lines of the file
\d\+ match one or more digits
\(\) keep the match in a capture group
\1,\2,\3 insert the first/second/third capture group

